# How to get rid of maven-antrun-plugin here?

Tags: maven, maven-3

The problem is as follows: I need to generate files in `META-INF` so that registering using [ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) works. FWIW, this is maven 3.0.4. The full link to the pom.xml file is [here](https://github.com/fge/uri-template/raw/master/pom.xml).

In order to generate these files, I use [this plugin](https://github.com/francisdb/serviceloader-maven-plugin) as follows:

```
<properties>
    <serviceName>com.github.fge.msgsimple.serviceloader.MessageBundleProvider</serviceName>
</properties>
<!-- .... -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>eu.somatik.serviceloader-maven-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>serviceloader-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <services>
                    <param>${serviceName}</param>
                </services>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

However, the generated file (`META-INF/services/xxxx`) don't find their way into the generated jar, so I have to resort to this (your eyes may bleed):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <property name="jarname"
                                value="${project.name}-${project.version}.jar"/>
                            <property name="victim"
                                value="${project.build.directory}/${jarname}"/>
                            <property name="serviceFile"
                                value="${project.build.directory}/classes/META-INF/services/${serviceName}"/>
                            <echo>${victim}</echo>
                            <echo>${serviceFile}</echo>
                            <jar destfile="${victim}" update="true">
                                <zipfileset file="${serviceFile}"
                                    prefix="META-INF/services/"/>
                            </jar>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I am aware of the shade plugin. I have tried it, battled with it for hours on end, with no success at all. It just wouldn't include the file. The above is the only solution that works for me.

But this solution is not sustainable. I also want to generate jar with dependencies, and in this case the service file needs to be appended to; and the solution above only works for jars without dependencies...

So, what plugin would you need to make the whole thing work seamlessly? How do you configure it?

Comment: I have [made a check](https://github.com/khmarbaise/uri-template/commit/dd781e45472c12dfb1b0d11667afdd6e062a3ce6) and found out the it seemed to be cause by the maven-bundle-plugin (which i not know in deepth). I can run without maven-antrun-plugin. Take a deep look into it.

Comment: @khmarbaise I will! Thanks! I need to understand the changes you have made first...

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the assembly plugin?  I find it quite powerful.
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

An example:
https://gist.github.com/wytten/5782232

Comment: Hmm, I use it but in its basic form only, I must admit I haven't dealt with the depths of it (its assembly descriptors in particular). I'll try and have a more than perfunctory look at it again. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't mind, a question: what use is an `id` in an `execution` target?

Comment: It appears to be of no use as it works equally well without it